# KinesisUtils.createStream error in Spark streaming + Kinesis

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to stream data from AWS Kinesis using [Spark Streaming + Kinesis Integration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kinesis-integration.html)

My code looks like:

```
sc = SparkContext('local[*]', 'app_name')
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

kinesisStream = KinesisUtils.createStream(ssc,
    kinesisAppName='kinesis_app_name',
    streamName='kinesis_stream_name',
    endpointUrl='https://kinesis.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
    regionName='ap-southeast-2',
    initialPositionInStream=InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON,
    checkpointInterval=10)
```

The command to run the script: `spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.2.0 script.py`. I'm using Spark 2.2.0 with Pyspark.

The error I got:

> ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/ubuntu/transformer/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1035, in send_command
>      raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/ubuntu/transformer/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 883, in send_command
>      response = connection.send_command(command)
>    File "/home/ubuntu/transformer/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1040, in send_command
>      "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "kinesis_to_s3.py", line 63, in 
>      checkpointInterval=streaming_interval)
>    File "/home/ubuntu/transformer/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/streaming/kinesis.py", line 92, in createStream
>      stsSessionName, stsExternalId)
>    File "/home/ubuntu/transformer/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in **call**
>      answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
>    File "/home/ubuntu/transformer/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 327, in get_return_value
>      format(target_id, ".", name))
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o27.createStream
>   Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/clientlibrary/lib/worker/InitialPositionInStream
>      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>      at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>      at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
>      at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
>      at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethodsByNameAndLength(ReflectionEngine.java:345)
>      at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:305)
>      at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
>      at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
>      at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>      at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>      at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
>      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitialPositionInStream
>      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>      ... 12 more